# Cypress (Electron) error on OpenShift "Failed to get 'appData' path" during End-to-end tests

Tags: docker, npm, electron, openshift, cypress

I tried to run cypress end-to-end tests in OpenShift. Locally it works, but in OpenShift occurs an error after starting the tests via the **cypress run** command.

Error message in OpenShift

```
> kfuvo-sfa-e2e@0.0.1 cypress-run /e2e  
    A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
    Uncaught Exception:
    Error: Failed to get 'appData' path
        at App.app._setDefaultAppPaths (/e2e/cypress-cache/3.6.0/Cypress/resources/electron.asar/browser/api/app.js:51:41)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/e2e/cypress-cache/3.6.0/Cypress/resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js:147:5)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:851:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:633:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:904:10)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:24:11
```

If I try to run the tests during the docker image build (**RUN npm run cypress-run**) everything works fine. The **cypress-run** npm script is just a shortcut for "cypress run".
The error occurs if I try to run the test after the container start (**ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/npm", "run", "cypress-run"]**).

It occurs in the electron part of the cypress implementation. I think the problem is, the docker image build is performed by the root user. The container will be started by a different user. It seems that electron is setting the appData path during the cypress installation to a directory of the root user. Later the user who is starting the container and is running the test is not able to access this appData folder.

I'm not very familiar with electron. Maybe anybody knows how to force electron to create this appData folder somewhere else?

Comment: Could you fix your problem?

Comment: Were are you able to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the `appData` path to a directory that the user has control over via the environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.

(Source: [electron documentation for `app.getPath`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname))

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions for the problem:

**1) Run cypress with the electron browser:**

In the dockerfile I replaced the electron.asar with a modified version

```
RUN rm -f /e2e/cypress-cache/3.6.0/Cypress/resources/electron.asar
COPY custom-electron-version/electron.asar /e2e/cypress-cache/3.6.0/Cypress/resources/
```

In the modified electron.asar the appData path was changed in the inital js file: `app.setPath("appData", 'customPath')`

Its not a clean solution and a problem on every update!

**2) Run cypress with chrome browser**

The better solution was just to change the browser to chrome:

```
cypress run --browser chrome
```

With chrome everything works as expected without dirty workarounds :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, i tried second solution , and still getting the same error.

Comment: If you are using chrome as browser, there can't be a electron error anymore. @itgeek are you sure chrome is really used as browser?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following environment variables on the openshift deployment for cypress worked for me.

- `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/test`

  - `/test` should contain the `cypress.json` file
- `CYPRESS_PORT=8080`

I discovered the `CYPRESS_PORT` issue by running `cypress run` in a terminal after setting `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to `/test` manually (ie. I ran `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/test` in a terminal) and getting the following error.

```
We found an invalid configuration value:

Expected `port` to be a number. Instead the value was: `"tcp://10.201.209.161:8080"`
```

I then ran `cypress info` and looked for environment variables that were set to `tcp://10.201.209.161:8080`.

```
Environment Variables:
CYPRESS_SERVICE_HOST: 10.201.209.161
CYPRESS_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR: 10.201.209.161
CYPRESS_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT: 8080
CYPRESS_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO: tcp
CYPRESS_SERVICE_PORT: 8080
CYPRESS_PORT: tcp://10.201.209.161:8080         <----------
CYPRESS_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP: 8080
CYPRESS_PORT_8080_TCP: tcp://10.201.209.161:8080
CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER: /root/.cache/Cypress
```

I then tried running `export CYPRESS_PORT=8080` followed by `cypress run` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue occurred when I tried to switch to the `user` instead of the `root`. So, Electron tried to obtain a path of the `home` folder. And simply adding a new user doesn't help.

After I added the home directory, it started to work.

```
RUN useradd -m user
USER user

ENTRYPOINT [path]
```